# How can i position rounded image in CSS?

Tags: html, css

So i have a rounded image and i need to position it on the left of the page, but for some reason when i do it, the corners of image get flat and image stays on the right instead of left. I searched on internet but can't seem to find what is my problem.

Css code:

```
.family{
  background: white; 
  overflow: hidden;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.family img{
  position: relative;
  object-position: 20px 100px;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  width:50%;
  height:50%;
  border-top-left-radius: 50% 50%;
  border-top-right-radius: 50% 50%;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 50% 50%;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 50% 50%;
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

Html code:

```
<div class="family">
        <img src="img/family.jpg">
</div>
```

Picture of an img
[image: Picture of an img]

Answer (score 0):

I removed `object-position:` and changed `top` and `left` to `0` and that worked just fine. here you can see

```css
.family{
  background: white; 
  overflow: hidden;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.family img{
  position: relative;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:50%;
  height:50%;
  border-top-left-radius: 50% 50%;
  border-top-right-radius: 50% 50%;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 50% 50%;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 50% 50%;
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

```html
<div class="family">
        <img src="https://thenextscoop.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/5-Mind-Blowing-Facts-from-the-Google-Logo-Design-History-1280x720.png">
</div>
```

Comment: ohh, it worked, but could i make it to be lower from the top? top: ..% doesn't work and it stays the same, i guess it's because of position:relative